# How to handle unexpected input stream from user?

Tags: java, sockets, error-handling, client, inputstream

I am learning basic socket I/O. I wonder what's the best way to deal with invalid client input. For example a Prime factor searcher on server side but user types a character to the client instead of a integer. 
Should we filter input stream at the client side at beginning or design a server that can handle the invalid input and send message to client, then to user or the most secure way is to implement both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder what's the best way to deal with invalid User to Client input for example, a Prime factor searcher on server side but user type a character to client instead of a integer.

The server should perform required validations of incoming message buffer. If it does not process the specific payload, it should know how to handle such unhandled messages. Infact you are required to read off the socket such messages in order to allow other well-formed messages to be read. For eg...assume you have M1,M2 coming on socket in that order. M1 is invalid while M2 is a well formed supported message. You will not be able to process M2 without removing M1. Hence, it is important that you handle such messages gracefully on the server.

> Should we filter input stream at the client side at the beginning or should we design the server to handle invalid inputs?

Client side code at times may not be in your control. If you have control over its source code, then by all means. The above rule also applies to server responding to client. It should follow proper Rules of engagement pre-agreed with client.